# How to subtract two columns with data format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" in csv file to extract time difference

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv file containing data in the following format:

```
"task_submit_time";"task_start_time"
"2017-02-12 15:24:32";"2017-02-12 15:27:31"
"2017-02-12 20:09:34";"2017-02-12 20:43:32"
"2017-02-12 23:58:52":"2017-02-13 00:23:31"
"2017-02-13 0:08:17";"2017-02-13 01:09:22"
"2017-02-13 03:38:35";"2017-02-13 03:53:21"
```

I need to get the time difference between the two columns:
task_start_time - task_submit_time.
I tried Excel sheet manipulation to add two extra columns by breaking date and time separately.
How to get total time difference including date and time in seconds.

Comment: When it comes in Excel should change the text to a date, then a simple formula `=B2-A2` should give the difference.  You may need to format the output column as a proper date time.

Comment: Open the csv file.  Use the text to columns wizard to split on the semicolon and define the date format as YMD; subtract one from the other and format the results appropriately.  Post back if you run into problems, **by editing your original post**, with a clear description of what you tried, and where you ran into a problem.